# How to include only specific columns as axis categories from an Excel Table

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, charts

I am familiar with Excel Tables, Pivot and so on.. but one tricky thing, how can I hide a column in the Table and also have that column not used as a category in my chart?

Excel has a solution by using Pivot as the best option, or without Table format.

Is there any other way?

For instance I would like to hide column B in my screenshot and not show those values in my chart. I don't want to delete that column.

p.s. Once when the data is hidden, still you can see them actually on chart. I dont need only on my sheet hidden but on Charts too.

[image]

This is just a sample of my data. The full table is larger.

Comment: Please edit your post to show some screenshots of your data and chart.

Comment: @FlexYourData  Updated

Comment: In your screenshot, which rows would you hide and want hidden from the sheet? Also, what is the general criteria for hiding a row?

Comment: @FlexYourData  For instance I would like to have Column B not repetative values..

Comment: So you want to hide some rows, but keep your chart exactly as it is (showing the hidden rows)?

Comment: The values in the combination of A and C are unique already. If you hide rows, you will also hide values in column D. Is this actually a question of chart readability? So at the moment it's too crowded because the values from column B are repeated in the chart for every row?

Comment: @FlexYourData YEa...readability. Wanted to ask if there is any other method instead of using Pivot where is easier to handle this.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio Yes, to avoid being crowded with duplicates. As I say, I was looking any other method but not Pivot. But if it is not, then it is like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to use a pivot, change the order of your columns so you can select just the columns you want. Cut the third column and insert it next to the first column. Then create the chart by just selecting the first, second and third columns.

[image]

Unfortunately with multi-level axis categories like this, I believe you can only control the vertical alignment of the inner-most axis. So, you can rotate the D1 column but not the Date, unless you put D1 to the left of Date in your data table.

PivotChart will give you more control over the formatting for nested categories.

EDIT:

It occurred to me that you could concatenate (join) the columns you want to use into a single column for the category. Then you would be able to rotate the whole thing:

```
=TEXT([@DATE],"dd/mm/yy")&" "&[@D1]
```

[image]

Comment: good point with rotate, I could technically just change the format of my date actually, to make it shorter and then "join" what is necessary! I think this should work actually like this! Thanks a lot!